# How to use class based views with more than one model?

Tags: django

I am using class based view with a created model, but I am not able to insert another model.

models.py:

```
class Test(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, 
   data = models.DateField(null=False, default=date.today)

class Test2(models.Model):
   teste = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE), 
   data = models.DateField(null=False, default=date.today)
```

views.py without the "Test2" model:

```
class IndexTemplateView(TemplateView):
  template_name = "index.html"

class TestCreateView(CreateView):
  template_name = "cadastro.html"
  model = Test
  form_class = InserePropriedadeForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy("test:list_test")

class TestListView(ListView):
  template_name = "list.html"
  model = Test
  context_object_name = "tests"


class TestDetailView(DetailView):
  template_name = "detail.html"
  model = Test
  fields = '__all__'
  context_object_name = 'test'
```

...
How can I add the model "Test2" to this view?

Comment: What do you mean, "add" it? How would that work? Do you perhaps just want to follow the relationship from a Test instance to the related Test2s? If so, what's stopping you doing that in the template?

Comment: I don't know where to add model test2 to views.py and forms.py

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. Why do you think you need to add it to the view? And you haven't mentioned anything about a form.